# `background-position` in CSS sprites using negative values

Tags: html, css, background-image

My question is about negative values with the `background-position` property.

I am reading HTML and CSS by Jon Duckett, and I have the following sprite where the height of each buttons is 40px.

[image]

I also produced some following code from the book to activate these sprites when the user hovers and clicks over these buttons.

```css
  a.button {
   height: 36px;
   background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/jnHrwk/button_sprite.jpg");
   text-indent: -9999px;
   display: inline-block;
  }
  a#add-to-basket {
   width: 174px;
   background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  a#framing-options {
   width: 210px;
   background-position: -175px 0px;
  }
  a#add-to-basket:hover {
   background-position: 0px -40px;
  }
  a#framing-options:hover {
   background-position: -175px -40px;
  }
  a#add-to-basket:active {
   background-position: 0px -80px;
  }
  a#framing-options:active {
   background-position: -175px -80px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Image Rollovers and Sprites</title>
</head>
<body>
 <a class="button" id="add-to-basket">Add to Basket</a>
 <a class="button" id="framing-options">Framing Options</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, in the example code, to choose framing options, the property `background-image` is given the value `-175px 0px`.

However, I thought that as the image is viewed via the co-ordinate system in CSS as shown below, I thought to go right, it would be `175px 0px` and to go down by 40px, `175px 40px`.

[image]

Why is going left and down given negative values in this example?

Comment: The default value of background is 0,0. If you set positive value for x it will move right if negative it moves left, same for y positive moves up, negative moves down. -175px -40px moves left and down. Its like when you set a margin top of positive or negative. It runs opposite margin when you set negative value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually moving/translating the sprite image in the coordinate system. As adapted from the answer to [css sprite with negative background positions not clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365061/css-sprite-with-negative-background-positions-not-clear), to display an image at position x=50 and y=20, move the sprite -50 to the left and -20 top in the coordinate system.

```
-50, -20
|-----------------------------------------------|
|                                               |
|       0,0                                     |
|       |--                                     |
|       |                                       |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|-----------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: This positioning system had me confused for a while. Thanks!